# Distinct entries from the set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

I am using the below query on the above database table but unable to get the distinct value. Help will be appreciated

`SELECT DISTINCT doctor_user_id, doctor_name, score, time_in_seconds FROM basket_game_master WHERE game_id='$game_id' ORDER BY score DESC, time_in_seconds ASC  LIMIT $limit`

The goal is to retrieve the doctor name with unique doctor_user_id who have more **score** with less **time_in_seconds**

Comment: use rank(), ranking over partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT doctor_user_id, doctor_name, score, time_in_seconds
FROM (SELECT bgm.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doctor_user_id ORDER BY score DESC, time_in_seconds ASC) as seqnum
      FROM basket_game_master bgm
      WHERE game_id = ?
     ) mgm
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY score DESC, time_in_seconds ASC
LIMIT ?;
```

Note the use of `?` for the *parameters*.  Do not munge the query string with literal values!  That poses a risk for SQL injections and for hard-to-debug syntax errors.